# Forwarding a request from a request to another, with a binary body

Tags: node.js, express, node-redis

I developing a REST API which delivers files from IoT devices.
In early versions, calling the REST api would make the backend tell the IoT devices to upload a file to the backend, and would pipe the request as a result:

```
// I build a "head" object from the device's request headers to set Content-Type, Cache-Control, etc.
res.writeHead(resCode, head);
device_req.pipe(res)
```

`device_res` being the request object from the call of the device, res being the response object from the call of the actual client. This works.

Now, I want to scale this. If I have multiple instances of my backend, the upload of the file by the device will not occur on the same instance. `device_req` and `res` are not in the same memory anymore. I decided to make my instance communicated through Redis.

Now, I store the buffer from the `device_req`  with something like this:

```
    var dataArray = []
    let object = {}

    req.on("data", function (data) {
        dataArray.push(Buffer.from(data, 'binary'))
    });

    req.on('end', async function (data) {
        object = { hello: "world", headers : req.headers, body : Buffer.concat(dataArray).toString() }
        await redis.set(<my-key>, JSON.stringify(object))
        res.json({})
    } )

    req.on('error', function (err) {
        res.json({})
    })
```

And I write this stored body to the resquest like this :

```
    let streamBody = Buffer.from(await redis.get(<my-key>))
    // I build the same "head" object from the device's request headers to set Content-Type, Cache-Control, etc.
    return res.writeHead(resCode, head).end(streamedBody)
```

I skipped the part where I wait until the request is written well, timeout handling, and so on.

The problem I have is that the encoding is not the same. In the first case I get an image. the `file` linux command reports `JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 448x252, components 3`
In the second case I just get binary data : 'data'
But the size is actually pretty close. What am I missing to get my file recognized as a jpeg again ?